# Can't see weight paint heatmap in blender 2.8 release candidate. What should I do to toggle it?

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-groups

I am trying to weight paint a terrain to adjust the amount of stones in some spots, but when I go in weight paint mode the heatmap is not showing, even if there are changes on the stones distribution when I paint.

Is there an option to toggle or another way to show it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can now pick weight painting heat map opacity, but for some reason it defaults to zero with some previously saved projects (probably because the category didn't exist before now). 
[image: Heat map opacity]
Hope this fixes your problem.